# Trailing n-day cumulative sum in mysql

Tags: mysql, sum

I have this structure:

```
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+--------+-------------+-------------+
| id                                   | start               | User   | billedHours | trail90dsum |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+--------+-------------+-------------+
| 2e88f9f9-2543-11eb-9d57-02b150913215 | 2018-10-04 11:00:00 | User 1 |       15.30 |        NULL |
| 2e89af0a-2543-11eb-9d57-02b150913215 | 2018-10-09 12:00:00 | User 1 |        0.40 |        NULL |
| 2e8a400b-2543-11eb-9d57-02b150913215 | 2018-10-09 17:00:00 | User 2 |        0.60 |        NULL |
| 2e8ae87d-2543-11eb-9d57-02b150913215 | 2018-10-25 17:30:00 | User 2 |        0.30 |        NULL |
| 2e8ba472-2543-11eb-9d57-02b150913215 | 2018-10-27 15:00:00 | User 3 |        1.20 |        NULL |
| 2e975c93-2543-11eb-9d57-02b150913215 | 2018-10-29 17:30:00 | User 3 |        0.30 |        NULL |
| 2e980477-2543-11eb-9d57-02b150913215 | 2018-11-02 13:30:00 | User 1 |        1.90 |        NULL |
| 2e98a874-2543-11eb-9d57-02b150913215 | 2018-11-03 12:00:00 | User 2 |        0.70 |        NULL |
| 2e993a7d-2543-11eb-9d57-02b150913215 | 2018-11-04 13:30:00 | User 3 |        1.30 |        NULL |
| 2ea9fa03-2543-11eb-9d57-02b150913215 | 2018-11-11 11:00:00 | User 1 |        0.90 |        NULL |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+--------+-------------+-------------+
```

I am looking for an UPDATE query that will fill the trail90dsum field with SUM(billedHours) for each user within the trailing 90 days (as of each start date).

I was able to construct a SELECT query with a join for reporting the data, but I can't transform it to work in the UPDATE syntax.

Thanks,
Phillip

Comment: Show your select?

Comment: Specify PRECISE MySQL version.

Comment: *I can't transform it to work in the UPDATE syntax.* `UPDATE table dst JOIN (your query) src USING (primary key column) SET dst.column=src.column`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. This query got the job done:

```
UPDATE mytable dst JOIN 
  (SELECT t1.user, t1.start, t1.billedHours, SUM(t2.billedHours) as last90
   FROM mytable as t1 JOIN mytable as t2 ON DATEDIFF(t1.start, t2.start) BETWEEN 0        
   AND 90 WHERE t1.user=t2.user
   GROUP BY t1.user, t1.start, t1.billedHours) src 
SET dst.trail90dsum=src.last90 
WHERE src.start=dst.start and src.user=dst.user
```

Thanks, -P